# Django JOIN not Working

Tags: python, django

My model is like this

```
class NounPlural(models.Model):
    idnoun_plural = models.IntegerField(db_column='idNoun_Plural', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    nns = models.TextField(db_column='NNS', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    news_idnews = models.ForeignKey(News, db_column='news_idnews')

class News(models.Model):
   idnews = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   source = models.TextField(blank=True)
   title = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

My view.py is like this

```
def allobj(request):
    obj_json = serializers.serialize('json', NounPlural.objects.select_related('news_idnews')[:5] )
    obj_list = json.loads( obj_json )
    json_data = json.dumps( obj_list )
    return HttpResponse( json_data, content_type='application/json' )
```

All I want to do is to get the `NounPlural` and also the title from `News`.When I go to `allobj` link I only get `NounPlural`.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `select_related` to do? Because it has no effect on the serialisation of the queryset, only on the database query where it performs an `INNER JOIN` and preloads the related objects into memory.

Answer (score -1):

In the [django documentation related to your question](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), I always see the need for a `.get(id=<something>)` with the `select_related()` call, like so:

```
Book.objects.select_related('person__city').get(id=4)
```

So shouldn't your call be:

```
NounPlural.objects.select_related('news_idnews').get(id=<Newsid>)[:5]
```

Is this the reason you only have a `NounPlural` and not the `QuerySet` you want ?